# sphericalutil.computeheading is use in android like in ios what we have to use

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
 float heading = (float) SphericalUtil.computeHeading(startValue, endValue);
marker.setRotation(heading);
```

This is way in android we use for heading.I need for heading multiple objects

Comment: which type of heading you want to show explain

Comment: i am developing app like uber. in this i am showing number of cars(images) in map  when drivers rotate my cars in map also be rotate.

Comment: please help me thanks in advance